# Scripts and css files not loading with jade + node js

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am learning mean stack development. I am using working out with some examples. I am trying to load my css files and javascript files in the `jade` file. files are appearing in the console --> Sources. But all the css files are loading with empty data and all the js files are loading with html data. 
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am having my `server.js` like this

```
var express = require("express");
var stylus = require("stylus");
var logger = require("morgan");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var app = express();
function compile(str,path) {
    return stylus(str).set('filename', path);
}
app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');
app.set('view_engine', 'jade');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(stylus.middleware({
    src: __dirname + '/public',
    compile:compile
}));
//defining routes
app.get('*', function (req,res) {
    res.render('index.jade');
});

var port = 3030;
app.listen(port);
console.log('starting listening....');
```

How to load the files properly in this scenario?

Comment: You're missing a [static file handler](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html).

Comment: Yes you are correct. Please submit this as answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requests for client side resources are not being handled by anything in your app, which means they get handled by your "catch-all" handler (`app.get('*', ...)`), which returns HTML (which explains why you are seeing HTML being returned for jQuery, for instance).

You want to use a [static file handler](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html) in your app to handle those requests:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

The `__dirname` argument points to the directory that holds your client side resources files, so you may need to change this.

Also, make sure that you add this line *above* your catch-all handler, otherwise the requests will still be handled by that instead of the static file handler.